# AWS Amplify publish fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I just created a new aws amplify application, and everything works locally.

Now I ran ´amplify add hosting´ like described in the docs and now I receive the following errors:

The docs: https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/hosting/q/integration/vue#add-hosting-to-your-app

> ... Add hosting to your app
>
> You can manually deploy your web app or setup automatic continuous deployment. In this guide we’ll cover how to manually deploy and host your static web app to quickly share with others. If you want to learn about continuous deployment instead, please follow this guide.
>
> From the root of your project, run the following command and select the bolded options.
>
> ```
> amplify add hosting
> ```
>
> ...

```
domi@Dominiks-MacBook-Pro fsbwo2 %amplify publish
✔ Successfully pulled backend environment dev from the cloud.

Current Environment: dev

| Category | Resource name | Operation | Provider plugin |
| | | | |
| Hosting | S3AndCloudFront | Create | awscloudformation |
| Auth | fsbwo29168573d | No Change | awscloudformation |
| Api | fsbwo2 | No Change | awscloudformation |
? Are you sure you want to continue? Yes
⠧ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

UPDATE_COMPLETE authfsbwo29168573d AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:14 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS hostingS3AndCloudFront AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:14 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) Resource creation Initiated
UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS authfsbwo29168573d AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS hostingS3AndCloudFront AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:13 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:09 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) User Initiated
⠙ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306-hostingS3AndCloudFront-AFU8FYAGR0W3 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:14 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) User Initiated
⠏ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS apifsbwo2 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:16 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
⠋ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

CREATE_FAILED amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306-hostingS3AndCloudFront-AFU8FYAGR0W3 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:18 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) The following resource(s) failed to create: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/.
CREATE_FAILED S3Bucket AWS::S3::Bucket Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:17 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) fsbwo2-20200805013947-hostingbucket-dev already exists
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS S3Bucket AWS::S3::Bucket Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:17 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306-apifsbwo2-1VC6S8GA5QGU AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:17 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) User Initiated
⠹ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS GraphQLSchema AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:22 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
⠋ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

CREATE_FAILED hostingS3AndCloudFront AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:687821944545:stack/amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306-hostingS3AndCloudFront-AFU8FYAGR0W3/dc55cef0-d709-11ea-a161-02508c92de46 was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/.
⠙ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306-apifsbwo2-1VC6S8GA5QGU AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) The following resource(s) failed to update: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/.
UPDATE_FAILED GraphQLSchema AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:23 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: FQ4WBHEZ2Y5K2Y8Y; S3 Extended Request ID: vNb1KbV1MoX4tQtCVFa+aTfYcVQN+JQGHM0QahezMSeaGnoJc+QSDmqoE1bvTOS1ydZXd5/JTuw=; Proxy: null)
⠙ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:26 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) The following resource(s) failed to create: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/. The following resource(s) failed to update: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/.
UPDATE_FAILED apifsbwo2 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:25 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) Resource update cancelled
⠙ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS apifsbwo2 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:30 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
UPDATE_COMPLETE authfsbwo29168573d AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:30 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS authfsbwo29168573d AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:29 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
⠋ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

UPDATE_COMPLETE GraphQLSchema AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:41 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
⠧ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306-apifsbwo2-1VC6S8GA5QGU AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:42 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
⠏ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

DELETE_IN_PROGRESS hostingS3AndCloudFront AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:54 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:53 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
UPDATE_COMPLETE apifsbwo2 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:52 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
⠹ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

DELETE_IN_PROGRESS amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306-hostingS3AndCloudFront-AFU8FYAGR0W3 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:54 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) User Initiated
⠹ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

DELETE_COMPLETE amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306-hostingS3AndCloudFront-AFU8FYAGR0W3 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:57 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
DELETE_SKIPPED S3Bucket AWS::S3::Bucket Wed Aug 05 2020 12:53:56 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
⠏ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

DELETE_COMPLETE hostingS3AndCloudFront AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:54:05 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
UPDATE_COMPLETE apifsbwo2 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:54:04 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
⠏ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE amplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:54:05 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
UPDATE_COMPLETE authfsbwo29168573d AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Wed Aug 05 2020 12:54:05 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
⠴ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...Error updating cloudformation stack
⠼ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

Following resources failed

Resource Name: S3Bucket (AWS::S3::Bucket)
Event Type: create
Reason: fsbwo2-20200805013947-hostingbucket-dev already exists

Resource Name: qyghpjwdvbds7ir3atltyisws4GraphQLSchema (AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema)
Event Type: update
Reason: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: FQ4WBHEZ2Y5K2Y8Y; S3 Extended Request ID: vNb1KbV1MoX4tQtCVFa+aTfYcVQN+JQGHM0QahezMSeaGnoJc+QSDmqoE1bvTOS1ydZXd5/JTuw=; Proxy: null)
URL: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=eu-central-1#/stacks/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aeu-central-1%3A687821944545%3Astack%2Famplify-fsbwo2-dev-230306-apifsbwo2-1VC6S8GA5QGU%2Fbc0bf480-d696-11ea-aceb-0a0c9a06689c/events

✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
An error occurred during the push operation: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
domi@Dominiks-MacBook-Pro fsbwo2 %
```